# Xml serialization/deserialization with unnumbered attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Although the Title might not make sense (I had a hard time describing this problem to shortly) I will try to explain here.

I have some XML that contains some values that will always be there, but it also contains an undefined number of other variables, Such as this:

```
<fooElements>
    <fooElement>
        <name>fooElem1</name>
        <barElement>
            <name>foobarElem1</name>
        </barElement> //There's an undefined number of these bar elements.
    </fooElement>
</fooElements>
```

Is there anyway process those `barElements` with the `fooElement` class?

My first though was to place a list inside of the `fooElement` class and then load the `barElement`(s) into that, but when i then serialize it back i get:

```
<fooElements>
    <fooElement>
        <name>fooElem1</name>
        <barList>
            <barElement>
                <name>foobarElem1</name>
            </barElement> //There's an undefined number of these bar elements.
        <barList>
    </fooElement>
</fooElements>
```

Which is not what i am looking for.

Is there any way i can store this undefined number of `barElements` inside the `fooElement` class without it showing in the xml?

Comment: FYI, those are elements, not attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your barList an `XmlElement`.  For example:

```
[XmlElement("barElement")]
public List<BarElementObject> BarElements { get; set; }
```

Comment: Everyone trying to add this should be aware that the XmlElement attribute referenced here is the one located in `System.Xml.Serialization`, not `System.Xml`